# Python smb connectivity

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to remote windows machine from unix using smb connection. However its failing. I am new to this field. Someone knows about this ?

```
import smb
conn = SMBConnection('username','password','Hostname','remote machine-name',use_ntlm_v2=True, sign_options=SMBConnection.SIGN_WHEN_SUPPORTED, is_direct_tcp=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'SMBConnection' is not defined
```

Working in python 2.7

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and perhaps https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks if you need help on how to format code in your questions.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your imports. Try this:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
```

instead of just `import smb`